# How to copy record using Hibernate (in Java)?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the best way to copy record in the same table ?

Something like that:

```
Address address = AddressDAO.get(id);
address.setId(null);
AddressDAO.add(address);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work but it's best if you express your intent (cloning) in your domain mode. Setting a field to null is just an implementation detail and carries no meaning.

```
Address address = AddressDAO.get(id);
Address clone = address.cloneMe();
AddressDAO.add(clone);
```

Comment: The problem I see with that is that if address.cloneMe() just sets the id to null, the method name is a lie. Calling it by itself does not produce a clone, it's still the same object.

Comment: It's a clone method. The original object is not affected. It returns a new instance. You could express it as a copy constructor, but I prefer the expressiveness of a (named) method for that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that should work.

I'm not sure whether hibernate doesn't check object references, so if this doesn't work you might need to create a new instance and copy all the properties (using `BeanUtils.copyProperties`, or even `BeanUtils.cloneBean(..)`), and then set the ID to null/0.

Answer (score 2):

Use on cascade Evict for that object in hibernate.

then

```
Address address = AddressDAO.get(id);
 AddressDAO.evict(address); //Internally session.evict(address);
address.setId(null); // If id is autogenerated
AddressDAO.add(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try it. If `adress` is still persistent (Session-bound) I would assume that there will be problems. You might need a `session.evict(address)` before setting the id to null.

Answer (score 0):

This won't make a deep copy...so your copy will refer to children objects of original objects.